# How to treat comments under a post, contained in another answer

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

Suppose a question was asked and some comments on this question (correctly) suggest using a specific tool for given problem.

Also suppose an answer below includes all the data provided in those comments (this answer could have been posted before or after the comments).

Should those comments be flagged (e.g. obsolete) or be ignored?

---

I am asking because they repeat things already existing in an another answer, so they are not adding anything of value. They are not harmful of course (apart from the repetition) but neither are they of use.

On the other hand though I don't know if they are worth moderation time (which might require additional effort checking an answer or 2 below the question).

Answer (score 3):

> Should those comments be flagged (e.g. obsolete) or be ignored?

While I suppose they could *technically* be flagged as obsolete, I'd argue they should simply be ignored.

This seems hardly worth a moderator's time.

Also, comments often enough contain more detailed information than answers, so you'd have to be super careful not to remove something of potential value.